# Отправка смс с кодом при авторизации

Tags: php, java, android

Здравствуйте. Дело в том, что я хочу реализовать авторизацию в своем приложении как на `Whatsapp`. То есть ведешь номер, приходит проверочный код. Введешь этот код и авторизовываешься.

Так вот, вопрос в том, как это в `PHP` реализовать? Перерыл везде, везде говорится, что нужно пользоваться сервисами, типа `sms`, `smsmobi` и тд. Но я в замешательстве, так как для сервиса уходит не мало денег, каждый раз при авторизации, не в регистрировании, отправлять `смс`. Я даже не знаю уже как быть, что делать. Разве `Whatsapp` пользуется такими `смс сервисами`?

Хочу поставить на этом точку, вообще нет никаких вариантов кроме использования таких сервисов?

Comment: Какой-то странный вопрос: типа *оказывается в магазине хлеб и водку дают только за деньги - подскажите где их брать бесплатно!*

Comment: @Barmaley, Если не знаешь, то и приходится задавать такие странные вопросы. Если у вас есть что сказать полезное, дабы помочь нуждающемуся, то пишите. А бесполезные комментарии лучше оставьте лучше под видео в ютьюб.

Comment: Мы как то для оповещений использовали календарь google. Через api планируется событие "вот прямо сейчас" а гугл умеет присылать sms с напоминанием о наступлении события. НО к сожалению некоторые смс от гугла приходили только через сутки. В общем отказались от такого способа передачи. А чудес не бывает, сотовые операторы хотят денег за свои услуги и если вы видите бесплатный сервис доставки смс, значит по каким то причинам кто то готов платить вместо вас и соответственно там наверняка будут какие либо ограничения, нестабильность доставки или просто в какой то момент перестанет работать

Comment: @TITAN вопрос выглядел странным - он просто противоречит здравой логике - если мы сами платим за отправку смс, то почему мы должны полагать что сервис не будет платить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Работать с отправкой SMS могут только авторизованные операторами связи сервисы, имеющие определенный договор на осуществление таких услуг. Отправка SMS всегда происходит через шлюз какого-то оператора.

**Следовательно**, самостоятельно отправлять SMS с номера с названием вашего сервиса не получится, хотя вы можете отправлять с собственного телефона, но это будет еще дороже.

Указанные расходы - это накладные расходы и отправка SMS всегда была дорогим способом регистрации пользователя.

Поэтому подключайте API и отправляйте SMS через любой сервис, если хотите подтверждать подлинность номера. Язык тут не важен, главное знать как отправлять элементарные HTTP запросы.

**P.S** Все сервисы терпят указанные расходы, как думаете, почему некоторые сервисы переходят на всякие push-уведомления, а смс оповещения стоят сколько-то рублей в месяц? :)

Comment: Извините, тут(http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=940) написали без сервисов через gmail, или я что то не понял? Хотя 2 раза перечитал.

Comment: Там электронная почта используется только как механизм коммуникации с гейтом, причём там используется Verizon, так что, скорее всего, SMS можно будет отправить только внутри Verizon, и не факт, что бесплатно. Кривое решение, если честно, но если есть бесплатные SMS от оператора, то почему бы и нет.

Comment: Еще один такой вопрос, вот я нашел и решил использовать готовое решение для аутентификации Twitter Digits (https://fabric.io/kits/ios/digits). И говорится что бесплатный, и какая им выгода?

Comment: @TITAN Такая политика у компании, может он вероятно до какого-то момента будет бесплатный.

Answer (score 3):

Отправлять SMS действительно придётся через SMS-шлюз, и это стоит денег. Крупные игроки могут позволить себе закупать рассылки большими объёмами, поэтому цена одного SMS получается достаточно небольшой.

Если вам нужна двухфакторная аутентификация, посмотрите в сторону [TOTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm), которая используется тем же Google. В этом случае проверочный код генерируется самим телефоном без необходимости отсылать SMS.